# GROUP BY selected columns except one

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a database table (MS Access) with many columns, but for this question only the first 4 matter.

[image]

The table is really basic but the point is that column `City` can and does have duplicates, same for column `ItemCode`, but the problem is with the 3rd column, where we have the book title. It is only normal to expect that this table has duplicates, as we sell the same book in many cities. BUT...what if the incompetent person populating the DB makes mistakes in the title of a book, as in first first row (The Guradian) and last row (The Guardiane)...or as in Lisbon, B22, with 2 different spellings?

If I simply use this code:

```
SELECT 
    [City], [ItemCode], [ItemName],
    SUM([Sales]) AS SalesQuant
FROM
    [TableA]
GROUP BY 
    [City], [ItemCode], [ItemName];
```

Then I still get duplicates in column ItemName because of the book title input mistakes.

Is there a way to group by City and ItemCode only and for column 3 to get ANY OF THE duplicate values (i.e. I don't care if the code returns "The Guradian" or "The Guardiane", I still know what it refers to = The Guardian)? The code above gives me 2 separate sales records for this book, when in reality I only care about the total of 1+4=5.

Thank you,
Stefan

Comment: if you really don't care which you get, just take the min or max of the title

Comment: Ideally, would not save ItemName in this table. Would have a table of BookTitles where each title is unique. Retrieve ItemName by joining tables.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I thought about solution of June7 and this is the plan in the longer run...

Comment: @Andrew - how can I take min or max of the title, that being a string? Does that work? I will try right away.

Comment: Solution to use MIN or MAX with string works!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew advised, if it doesn't matter which ItemName spelling is retrieved, use Min() or Max() (or even First() or Last()) in aggregation.

```
SELECT 
    [City], [ItemCode], Max([ItemName]) AS Title, SUM([Sales]) AS SalesQuant
FROM
    [TableA]
GROUP BY 
    [City], [ItemCode];
```

However, ideally would not save ItemName in this table. Would instead have a table of BookTitles where each title is unique then retrieve ItemName by joining tables.

Comment: I agree. A separate table of unique book title is the cleanest way to go. I intend to create one, but it will take quite some time...imagine the list of book titles with various spellings per title is about 200K records!

Comment: Creating a table of unique titles would be quick (by using the same aggregate function) but going through that new table to correct misspellings would be tedious.